# Jquery/CSS - how to clear a CSS-background set in another file I can't edit

Tags: jquery, css, background, background-image

I'm trying to overwrite a button background, which is:

```
background: url("path/to/image.jpg") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
```

I want to get rid of the image, but as I cannot access the file, I need to overwrite via CSS or Jquery.

Any idea how I can do this, since something easy like `background: none` doesn't work, I cannot use Jquery to remove the whole class and I don't want to put in a transparent 1x1px png and waste an HTTP request. The image has to go...  any idea what I can do?

Thanks for help.

Comment: It looks like a specificity issue. What's the order of the `link` tags in your HTML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Background is a compound property, you can target just the image by `background-image: none`. More info on the property from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-image) and [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-image).

Be advised that browser support for this may vary - I've done a quick Google search and it seems that IE and Safari may have issues with this.

To target this property in vanilla JS, you'd use camel case:

```
element.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
```

Comment: that actually works after adding !important... I don't know what I had been doing the last half hour... THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

If `!important` doesn't do the trick (see Pbirkoff's answer) then you can look directly at the original css or use some type of inspection tool (e.g. firebug).  From there it's a matter of the css selection heirarchy (see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade).  What you'll want to do is either create a new rule that takes precedence over the original or recreate the exact rule and just knock out the image.  For example...

...in `original.css`:

```
.something {
  background: url("path/to/image.jpg") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
}
```

...in `your.css`:

```
.something {
  background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does putting !important after the value work? e.g:

```
background: none!important;
```

Comment: also thank you but Alex got me on the right track. I had been !important-ing for a while.